# Query is being executed infinitely in IntelliJ IDEA's Database console

Tags: console, intellij-idea, hsqldb

Do you guys know why SQL query might be being executed infinitely in IntelliJ IDEA's Database console unless I hit "Terminate" button ?

I have Intellj IDEA 11 and HSQLDB. When I run simple query it keeps printing something like this in output

```
[2011-12-15 00:19:32] 9 row(s) affected in 2724 ms
[2011-12-15 00:19:32] 9 row(s) affected in 2724 ms
[2011-12-15 00:19:32] 9 row(s) affected in 2724 ms
[2011-12-15 00:19:32] 9 row(s) affected in 2724 ms
```

and after I hit "Terminate" it spits

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: localhost; nested exception is: 
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
Caused by: java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: localhost; nested exception is: 
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:601)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:198)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:184)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:110)
    at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invokeRemoteMethod(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:178)
    at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:132)
    at $Proxy149.getWarnings(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:351)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:213)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:529)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:478)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:375)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:189)
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIDirectSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIDirectSocketFactory.java:22)
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIMasterSocketFactory.java:128)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:595)
    ... 22 more
```

It's not super-big deal but it's little bit annoying.

Any ideas why it's happening and how to fix it ?

Comment: What is the exact SQL query that leads to this behavior?

Comment: Any ideas ? I can prodive more information if necessary.

Comment: Maybe the database server is not live. To check, try connecting with a different tool, such as HSQL DatabaseManager.